# IllegalArgumentException in Bitmap.getPixels()

Tags: android, bitmap, pixel

I'd like to copy the data from a Bitmap into an `int[]` using `getPixels()`, this is my current code:

```
int[] pixels = new int[myBitmap.getHeight() * myBitmap.getWidth()];
myBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0,
        myBitmap.getHeight(), myBitmap.getWidth());

for(int i = 0; i < myBitmap.getHeight() * myBitmap.getWidth(); i++) {
    Log.e(TAG, "pixel"+i+"" +pixels[i]);
}
```

But it's throwing an exception:

```
05-04 20:24:08.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5700): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-04 20:24:08.296: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5700): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()
05-04 20:24:08.296: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5700):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelsAccess(Bitmap.java:818)
05-04 20:24:08.296: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5700):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixels(Bitmap.java:771)
05-04 20:24:08.296: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5700):     at com.tecmark.Jjilapp$TouchView.onDraw(Jjilapp.java:206)
```

Any ideas? I just specified the y param as 0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have your width and hight switched.

`myBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getHeight(), myBitmap.getWidth());`

vs

`public void getPixels (int[] pixels, int offset, int stride, int x, int y, int width, int height)`
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels(int[], int, int, int, int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 11):

I think there's a typo in this code. Try this:

```
myBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0,
   myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
```

Comment: Hello , I have a local byte[] depthBuffer, I want to generate Bitmap using it , any one have ide a abt it : 
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(depthBuffer , 0, depthBuffer .length); ..but bitmap obj resonfing null, any one have idea about this?
 I am getting "SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null" exception.

Comment: The `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` method is used to decode binary JPEG-data stored in a byte array. In order to solve your problem you can try to create an empty `Bitmap` using the `Bitmap.createBitmap()` method with the `ALPHA_8` config and then copy bytes from the array to the bitmap with the `Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer()` method. Use the `ByteBuffer.wrap()` method to create a `Buffer` from the byte array.